# How to print a number upto 4 decimal places without rounding off in java without using BigDecimal

Tags: java

if input = 31.6227890
then output = 31.6227 
but the output is coming as 31.6228

Comment: What type are you working with?  `double`, or something else?  Note that floating point arithmetic is not exact in Java.

Comment: Please make a [mcve] to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am working with double

Comment: when printing decrease by 0.00005 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

float i=(float)((int) (31.6227890 *10000))/10000;

System.out.println(i);

Comment: As float only has 6 digits of accuracy this won't work for "large" numbers around 100 or more

Comment: can overflow the int as well

Comment: Correct, the smallest value this fails for is 1024.0003, see my answer

Answer (score 4):

You can use below function:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public static double formatValue(Double number) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####0.0000");
        return Double.parseDouble(df.format(number));
    }
```

**Edit** :
you have to add below code for rounding off.

```
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
```

**Input = 31.6227890**

**Output = 31.6227**

Comment: Are you sure this *doesn't round* the result?

Comment: 1.) This rounds. 2.) Depending on your locale it will output the string being comma seperated over point seperated (`2,1234` not `2.1234`) which then again can't be parsed back.

Comment: thanks but it's return 31.6228 instead of 31.6227 with this approach

Comment: @PeterLawrey It rounds the result

Comment: can I truncate the value after rounding it upto 5 decimals

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer for rounding off :)
Thanks for your attention

Comment: But I don't want it to round off  the number

Comment: Input = 31.6227890
OutPUT =  31.6227

Answer (score 2):

If you want to round down, you can use truncation like this.

```
double d = 31.6227890;
d = ((long) (d * 10000)) / 10000.0; // truncates down to 0
System.out.println(d);
```

prints

```
31.6227
```

Note: this might print less than 4 digits. If you always want 4 you need to use formatting.

```
d = 31.60007890;
d = ((long) (d * 10000)) / 10000.0; // truncates down to 0
System.out.println(d);
System.out.printf("%.4f%n", d);
```

prints

```
31.6
31.6000
```

NOTE: For large values you wouldn't round them as this would result in an overflow.

```
private static final double WHOLE_NUMBER = 1L << 53;
public static double trunc4(double d) {
    final double factor = 1e4;
    return Math.abs(d) >= WHOLE_NUMBER / factor 
           ? d 
           : ((long) (d * factor)) / factor;
}
```

The point at which you get an error is for numbers so large they are whole numbers anyway (due to the limits of the precision on double)

NOTE: If you used `float` the limit at which you would get a precision error is for much smaller values.

```
double d = 1024.00039999;
float f= (float) (long) (d * 10000) / 10000;
System.out.println(f);
```

prints

```
1024.0002
```

Comment: There's the usual fp inaccuracies to deal with it you want more decimal places. This will also not work correctly for large values of d (i.e. we use accuracy and risk overflows). For"normal" values this will be fine though

Answer (score 1):

You can round down using a BigDecimal:

```
new BigDecimal(31.6227890d).setScale(4, RoundingMode.DOWN)
```

That returns the desired result: `31.6227`.

For a `double`, you can use `.doubleValue()`:

```
new BigDecimal(31.6227890d).setScale(4, RoundingMode.DOWN).doubleValue()
```

Comment: Note `System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.0003d).setScale(4, RoundingMode.DOWN));` prints `0.0002` I suspect `BigDecimal.valueOf(...)` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply it per 1000, use Math.floor() and divide it per 1000

```
    double a = 10.345665654;
    double b = Math.floor(a * 10000) / 10000;
    System.out.println(b);
```